# Global keyboard hook that doesn't disable user input outside of form

Tags: c#, hook

So i'm trying to find a global keyboard hook for C#. I found a class that worked to hook the keyboard, but it disabled the keyboard outside of the form. This is the current keyboard hook:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project
{

    class globalKeyboardHook
    {

        public delegate int keyboardHookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);

        public struct keyboardHookStruct
        {
            public int vkCode;
            public int scanCode;
            public int flags;
            public int time;
            public int dwExtraInfo;
        }

        const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
        const int WM_KEYUP = 0x101;
        const int WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 0x104;
        const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x105;

        public List<Keys> HookedKeys = new List<Keys>();

        IntPtr hhook = IntPtr.Zero;

        public keyboardHookProc SAFE_delegate_callback;
        public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;

        public event KeyEventHandler KeyUp;

        public globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            hook();
        }

        ~globalKeyboardHook()
        {
            unhook();
        }

        public void hook()
        {
            IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
            SAFE_delegate_callback = new keyboardHookProc(hookProc);
            hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, SAFE_delegate_callback, hInstance, 0);

        }

        public void unhook()
        {
            UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhook);
        }

        public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam)
        {

            try
            {
                if (code >= 0)
                {
                    Keys key = (Keys)lParam.vkCode;
                    if (HookedKeys.Contains(key))
                    {
                        KeyEventArgs kea = new KeyEventArgs(key);
                        if ((wParam == WM_KEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN) && (KeyDown != null))
                        {
                            KeyDown(this, kea);
                        }
                        else if ((wParam == WM_KEYUP || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP) && (KeyUp != null))
                        {
                            KeyUp(this, kea);
                        }
                        if (kea.Handled)
                            return 1;
                    }
                }

                return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
            }
            catch { return 0;  }
        }


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, keyboardHookProc callback, IntPtr hInstance, uint threadId);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hInstance);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int CallNextHookEx(IntPtr idHook, int nCode, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    }
}
```

Would anyone know how to change the exisiting hook so that it still allows the user to type, or know of another example that does this.

Thanks.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code, I'd have to guess you are just using it incorrectly.  Avoid setting the Handled property to true, especially when another process owns the foreground window.

Comment: Ok, thanks. removing the check allowed it to work.

Comment: I need something like this, but i dont know how to implement properly. I created a new c# console application and add new cllas in which i puted your code and then in my main class Program.cs i cant call any of this functions (hook()...). can you please help me how to properly implement this code into a new project and how its working?

Answer (score 2):

Following a comment by Hans Passant. I looked at this bit of code here:

```
if (kea.Handled)
   return 1;
```

And changed it to

```
if (!kea.Handled)
  return 1;
```