# How to call a keyboard key press programmatically?

Tags: c#, keyboard, overriding, capslock

**Problem**:
Calling a keyboard key to be pressed, from a piece of C# code
but here's the catch: the key-press should not be limited to the process/application
but received by the entire operating system, so also when the program is in the background and a different form/program has focus

**Goal**:
make a program that locks the state of <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> and <kbd>NumLock</kbd>

**Background**:
I have a laptop, and these 2 keys frustrate me to much, I want to make a application that runs in the background, and that disables <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as soon as it gets accidentally enabled, and for <kbd>NumLock</kbd> to never be disabled, also, I want to extend my knowledge about coding, I have tried to find solutions, but none of them solve the (entire) problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class CapsLockControl
{

    public const byte VK_NUMLOCK = 0x90;
    public const byte VK_CAPSLOCK = 0x14;

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags,UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);
    const int KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x1;
    const int KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x2;

    public static void Main()
    {
        if (Control.IsKeyLocked(Keys.CapsLock))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caps Lock key is ON.  We'll turn it off");
            keybd_event(CapsLockControl.VK_CAPSLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, (UIntPtr) 0);
            keybd_event(CapsLockControl.VK_CAPSLOCK, 0x45, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,
                (UIntPtr) 0);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Caps Lock key is OFF");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to hook the keyboard by using user32.dll.
This codeProject [sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook) should get you started

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable capslock from actually being pressed at all you can do that with

```
SetWindowsHookEx
```

There is plenty of information here about how to use it. For example

[Global Hook Keylogger problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540572/global-hook-keylogger-problem)

[Global keyboard hook that doesn't disable user input outside of form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567127/global-keyboard-hook-that-doesnt-disable-user-input-outside-of-form)

And ofcourse msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can try a CodePlex project that simulates both Keyboard and Mouse clicks.

Its called Windows Input Simulator and it can be found [Here](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)