# how to change language of Virtual Keyboard in C# or VB?

Tags: c#, vb.net, keyboard, virtual, on-screen-keyboard

I want to change language of OSK in my Project when show.
How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
Private oskProcess As Process
oskProcess = Process.Start("osk")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think OSK can't do this, but TabTip can. 
Maybe this will help you.

```
Private tabtipProcess As Process
tabtipProcess = Process.Start("tabtip")
```

and read this article, tells about how to control tabtip. It may be usefull [Start TabTip with numpad view open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140852/start-tabtip-with-numpad-view-open)