# How to show tabtip in numeric mode?

Tags: windows, delphi, firemonkey, virtual-keyboard

How to display `tabtip` in numeric mode programatically with delphi?

I need the virtual keyboard, tabtip, to be shown with only numbers when the focus is on a text editing decimal type.

Comment: FireMonkey does not allow you to specify the editing mode when displaying the virtual keyboard manually. The `TEdit.KeyboardType` property dictates what editing mode is used when the virtual keyboard is displayed when the `TEdit` has input focus.

Comment: I have a tablet windows 10 which has to run an application with numeric input fields

Comment: It is the responsibility of the input fields to specify what type of keyboard input they expect

Comment: Okay, but I need when the numerical type field receives the focu, show the virtual keyboard of windows 10 (TabTip) with only the numbers.

Comment: Is there something in my earlier comments that is unclear to you? You are approaching this issue the wrong way. You are not suppose to display the keyboard manually, the input field is. You are not supposed to configure the keyboard edit mode manually, the input field is.

Comment: Related: [Windows 8 Desktop App: Open tabtip.exe to secondary keyboard (for numeric textbox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646684/)

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking for an answer to this one and was not able to find one. I figured that you can set the input scope of the TEdit on the OnShow event of the form or the OnEnter event of the TEdit itself.

Add Winapi.MsCTF to the uses, and call:

```
  ..
  SetInputScope(Edit1.Handle, IS_NUMBER);
  ..
```